# How to store $ in a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I want to store a $ character in a PHP variable.

```
$var = "pas$wd";
```

I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: wd in C:\xxxxx  on line x
```

Help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use single-quoted strings :

```
$var = 'pas$wd';
```

This way, variables won't be interpolated.

Else, you can escape the `$` sign, with a `\` :

```
$var = "pas\$wd";
```

And, for the sake of completness, with PHP >= 5.3, you could also use the NOWDOC *(single-quoted)* syntax :

```
$var = <<<'STRING'
pas$wd
STRING;
```

As a reference, see [the **Strings** page of the PHP manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) *(quoting a couple of sentences)* :

> Note: [...] variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters will
>   not be expanded when they occur in
>   single quoted strings.

And :

> If the string is enclosed in
>   double-quotes (`"`), PHP will
>   interpret more escape sequences for
>   special characters: 
> `\$`  : dollar
>   sign

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes inhibit expansion:

```
var = 'pas$wd';
```

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes enable variable interpolation. So if you are using double quotes, you need to escape the `$` else you can use single quote which do not do variable interpolation.

```
$ var = "pas\$wd";
```

or

```
$ var = 'pas$wd';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = 'pas$wd';
$var = "pas\$wd";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Use the following code 
$var='pass$wd'
```